# Configure Socks Proxy iPhone

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks

I am currently in China and I would like to bypass the censorship. (Mostly for Google and Netflix)

I have a linux host in France that I could use for the SSH tunnel (let's call it user@domain.fr)

In my Mac Book Pro, I typed the command line 
`ssh -ND 9999 user@domain.fr`, I configured my socks proxy, and everything worked fine.

**First idea:** I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.systutorials.com/4876/how-to-configure-ios-for-iphone-and-ipad-to-use-socks-proxy-created-by-ssh/)

My Pac file is :

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host)
{ 
     return "SOCKS domain.fr:9999";
}
```

I put the file proxy.pac in my linux host via `scp` command. When I checked the URL of the file with Mobile Safari, it displayed the code written above, so I guess it can access it.

Then I configured the iOS device (Proxy Http -> Auto -> URL...) but it didn't work. What's strange is that I can still access non-censored website (like Apple), but I can't access censored-one (Facebook, Twitter) I would have thought that configuring the Http Proxy to Auto would affect the whole Web Browser.

Anyway, I wonder if that's because I need an authentication to access my host. And if that's so, how could I make it work?

**Second idea:** : I tried port forwarding with this [tutorial](https://crystalnixhq.gitbooks.io/serverauditor-documentation/content/using_sa/portforwarding_md.html)
Since my basic needs are Google and Netflix, I used Termius and configured the port forwarding as followed :

Port Forwarding > Local 
Host : domain.fr:22
Port from : 9998
Destination : google.com
Port to : 80

Port Forwarding > Local 
Host : domain.fr:22
Port from : 9999
Destination : netflix.com
Port to : 80

Then I tried to access via localhost:9998 and localhost:9999.

For Netflix, I have a Http Status 404 : the requested resource is not available.
For Google, I have a Http Status 404 : the requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

With the said configuration the HTTP traffic is routed to the proxy. But there is a catch, then DNS lookup which is not an HTTP protocol will fail.

Answer (score 0):

for your first idea, this script may help

https://github.com/wooowooo/proxyMyPhone

you can try running this script on your linux host

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Are you the author of this script?